# Mongo featureComptabilityVersion upgrade to 5.0 stuck since hours

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to set featureComptabilityVersion to 5.0 from current 4.4 and my process is still stuck since an hour. What should I do?

```
    {
        "type" : "op",
        "host" : "ip-10-0-61-19:27017",
        "desc" : "conn91562",
        "connectionId" : 91562,
        "client" : "127.0.0.1:47472",
        "appName" : "MongoDB Shell",
        "clientMetadata" : {
            "application" : {
                "name" : "MongoDB Shell"
            },
            "driver" : {
                "name" : "MongoDB Internal Client",
                "version" : "5.0.16"
            },
            "os" : {
                "type" : "Linux",
                "name" : "Ubuntu",
                "architecture" : "x86_64",
                "version" : "18.04"
            }
        },
        "active" : true,
        "currentOpTime" : "2023-04-25T12:46:00.059+05:30",
        "effectiveUsers" : [
            {
                "user" : "root",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ],
        "threaded" : true,
        "opid" : 552338,
        "lsid" : {
            "id" : UUID("4672b3ae-c39a-4eb8-88ea-e2e4528d6edb"),
            "uid" : BinData(0,"Y5mrDaxi8gv8RmdTsQ+1j7fmkr7JUsabhNmXAheU0fg=")
        },
        "secs_running" : NumberLong(28545),
        "microsecs_running" : NumberLong("28545923244"),
        "op" : "command",
        "ns" : "admin.$cmd",
        "command" : {
            "setFeatureCompatibilityVersion" : "5.0",
            "lsid" : {
                "id" : UUID("4672b3ae-c39a-4eb8-88ea-e2e4528d6edb")
            },
            "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1682398401, 1),
                "signature" : {
                    "hash" : BinData(0,"el/iawh9ngULzalgcpAxGJfEi1A="),
                    "keyId" : NumberLong("7212556859553611777")
                }
            },
            "$db" : "admin"
        },
        "numYields" : 0,
        "waitingForLatch" : {
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2023-04-25T04:53:34.236Z"),
            "captureName" : "AnonymousLockable"
        },
        "locks" : {
            "Mutex" : "W"
        },
        "waitingForLock" : false,
        "lockStats" : {
            "Mutex" : {
                "acquireCount" : {
                    "W" : NumberLong(2)
                }
            }
        },
        "waitingForFlowControl" : false,
        "flowControlStats" : {
            
        }
    },
```

Comment: It says `"secs_running" : NumberLong(2162)` which is just a few minutes.

Comment: Yesterday I let it ran for full night. I killed it this morning only.

Comment: According documentation you can redo the command as many times as you want.

Comment: yes, but Did anybody else also found out that upgrading it to v5.0 from v4.4 takes a bit longer? Or my DB has some issue?

Comment: Assuming you actually posted new output and didn't just update the time fields, that operation has been waiting for a lock a very long time.  If you don't have anything in progress other than this change, you may need to restart to get rid of whatever is holding that lock.

Comment: But `"waitingForLock" ` is set to `false`